# How to encrypt multiple files using python

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to search for .txt files in a specified folder and encrypt each one of the .txt files found using my encryption algorithms. However I cannot seem to be able to figure out how to encrypt all the .txt files found within the folder and rename them

this is the code I am working with currently

```
import time, os, sys, encrypt, decrypt, caesarCipher, reverseCipher, vigenereCipher, glob

def main():
    outputFilename = 'ABC.encrypted.txt'
    mKey = 5
    myMode  = 'encrypt'


    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Ransom'):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith((".txt")):
            inputFilename = os.path.join(root, file)

    if not os.path.exists(inputFilename):
        print('The file %s does not exist. Exiting....' % (inputFilename))
        sys.exit()

    fileObj = open(inputFilename)
    content = fileObj.read()
    fileObj.close()

    print ('%sing...' % (myMode.title()))

    startTime = time.time()
    if myMode == 'encrypt':
        translated = encrypt.encryptMess(mKey, content, myMode)
    elif myMode == 'decrypt':
        translated = decrypt.decryptMess(mKey, content, myMode)

    outputFileObj = open(outputFilename, 'w')
    outputFileObj.write(translated)
    outputFileObj.close()

    print('Done %sing %s (%s characters).' % (myMode, inputFilename, len(content)))
    print('%sed file is %s.' % (myMode.title(), outputFilename))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I really appreciate any help to guide me into achieving this.

Comment: same way you `print` the names of the files inside the `for file in files:` loop, you should do the same regarding the encryption. Keep doing it **inside** the `for` loop.

Comment: I tried doing that but it does not work. This is the code I tried    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/Users/rose_/Desktop/Ransom'):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith((".txt")):
                Inputfilename =  os.path.join(root, file))

Comment: update the question with the code you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code iterates over all the files in a given folder and calls a designated method whenever the file is '*.txt'

```
import os

baseUrl = './'

def encryptFile(filename):
    # process one file here
    print baseUrl + filename

alist = next(os.walk(baseUrl))[2]
for i in xrange(len(alist)):
    afile = alist[i]
    if afile[-4:] == '.txt':
        encryptFile(afile)
```